# (SocketIO.Swift) socket.on callback not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am implementing SocketIO in my app. I have tested the server url, key for the handler is working fine(I tested in android). Following is my code in iOS.

```
var socket:SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient.init(socketURL: URL.init(string: "My Server Url")!, config: [.log(true),.forcePolling(true)])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    socket.onAny({

        data in

        print("ANy event =====> \(data)" )

    })
    socket.on("My key", callback: {

        data,ack in

        print("call back called \(data)    \(ack)")

    })
    socket.connect()
}
```

I am able to see logs and can also see connect event in the log but I am not getting any callback for "My key" callback. Did I do something wrong or missed something? I tested the same in android and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: On any callback its working???

Comment: It is working for .connect call back

Comment: I am getting .connect call back but server side it shows that i am not connecting. Should I need to add any permission or something for this?. I added App Transport Security settings(and allow arbitrary load).